# ERROR pulp CBC Solver [WinError 5] Access Denied

Tags: python, pulp, coin-or-cbc

I've compiled a version of CBC for multithreading but i'm struggling connecting it to
pulp.

To be more specific I've linked the solver to pulp using these lines of code:

```
pathToSolver = "C:\\Users\\ ... \\coin_or\\Cbc\\MSVisualStudio\\v16\\ReleaseParallel"

solver = COIN_CMD(path=pathToSolver,threads=8)
checksol = prob.solve(solver)
```

But when I run the code it crash with this error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied
```

I've tried to change permissions to `cbc.exe` giving to it all the permissions but the result was the same.